# Trying to skip exception from test method by throwing skip exception but test cases still pass

Tags: selenium, testng-dataprovider

I'm trying to skip exception from a test method in testing. Using data provider to get data from Excel and based on a condition I want to skip tests, I'm throwing skip exception but these test cases are also shown as passed. My code is as follows:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "postProperty")
public static void postProperty(Object testCaseNo , Object propertyFor , Object testCaseFlag , Object propertyType , Object propertyCode){
    int ppTestCaseNo = (int) testCaseNo;
    String ppPropertyFor = propertyFor.toString();
    String ppTestCaseFlag = testCaseFlag.toString().trim();
    String ppPropertyType = propertyType.toString();
    int ppPropertyCode = (int) (double) propertyCode;
    boolean propertyIdFlag = true;
    try {
        if (ppTestCaseFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
            GenericFunctions.excelDataForTestCase(ppTestCaseNo);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            String browserType = workSheet.getRow(ppTestCaseNo).getCell(5).getStringCellValue().trim();
            switch (browserType) {
                case "Deployment" :  
                    driver.get("http://deployment.magicbricks.com/postproperty/post-property-for-sale-rent/residential-commercial");
                    break;
                case "Live" : 
                    driver.get("http://post.magicbricks.com/postproperty/post-property-for-sale-rent/residential-commercial");
                    break;
                case "Staging" :
                    driver.get("http://staging.magicbricks.com/postproperty/post-property-for-sale-rent/residential-commercial");
                    break;
                case "NewMB" :
                    driver.get("http://newMB.magicbricks.com/postproperty/post-property-for-sale-rent/residential-commercial");
                    break;
            }
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            if (ppPropertyType.equalsIgnoreCase("Multistorey Apartment")){
                boolean propertyIdPostedFlag = PostProperty.functionPostPropertyMultiStoreyApartment(ppPropertyType , ppPropertyCode ,driver , robot, ppTestCaseNo ,log);
                Assert.assertEquals(propertyIdFlag, propertyIdPostedFlag);
            }
            else{
               boolean propertyIdPostedFlag =PostProperty.functionPostPropertyOtherPropertyType(ppPropertyType , ppPropertyCode ,driver , robot, ppTestCaseNo ,log);
               Assert.assertEquals(propertyIdFlag, propertyIdPostedFlag);
            }
        }
        else if (ppTestCaseFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
           throw new SkipException("Skipping test case for "+ppPropertyType);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are catching the SkipException in the catch (Exception...) and just printing a stacktrace. Thus testNG has no idea about this exception being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are catching `Exception` in your whole code after throwing `SkipException` .

You know `Exception` is a base class while `SkipException` it's child, so if you use `catch (Exception e)`,  it will catch all the exception which would be throw in your code.

So If you want to throw `SkipException` and catch all exception except this, you need to catch possible individual child exception which could be throw in your code instead of  `Exception`.

I'm giving you example with catching some possible exception which could be throw in your code :-

```
try {
    // Your code here

   throw new SkipException("Skipping test case for "+ppPropertyType);
}catch (WebDriverException e){
}catch (IllegalStateException e){
}......
```

Comment: No need for individual exceptions. In the catch(Exception ...) check if exception is an instanceOf SkipException. If true then throw it again. Other exceptions can be treated however you want

Comment: @Grasshopper yes you are absolutely right?? But is this make sense catch then throw again??I think If you are knowing possible individual exception best way to handle it individually with individual message for better known which exception actually occurred...:)

Comment: Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as well if it worked..:)